# Get SID in static block in Magento url

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, customer-session

I have `multistore magento with multi domains`.
I want to add store switcher in main menu in mobile view. But giving store1.com as href do not call customers session to get shared shopping cart between stores.
What should i add after href="http://domain1.com" in static block that i use in mobile menu?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 possible store configurations:

1. If your websites are located in one domain, but in different directories, e.g. "www.example.com/stores/store1" and "www.example.com/stores/store2" you can setup your "Cookie Path" to "/stores/" in System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie Management.
2. If your websites are located in different sub-domains e.g. "store1.example.com" and "store2.example.com" you can setup "Cookie Domain" to ".example.com" in System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie Management.
3. If you have different domains, in this case you can add session ID to the URL for another store. Use this construction "Mage::getModel('core/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('...')" to get the URL with session parameter.

After that your customers will be able to switch between multi-stores Magento websites without re-login. In other words, if customer will login in one Magento website, he will be able to see another multi-store Magento website using his first store account.
But the cart will be different for each Magento website.

Comment: it'll grateful to you ,if you can accept my answer above.

Comment: In static block cant use php
here is code I use in block for mobile but does not share shoping cart, no SID:
<li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children menu-parent-item">
        <a href="javascript:;">Stores</a>
        <ul>            
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children menu-parent-item">
                <a class="level1" href="http://domain2"><span>domain2</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children menu-parent-item">
                <a class="level1" href="http://domain1.com/"><span>domain1</span></a>
            </li>

Comment: you can write php code in a phtml file then call it in your static block like this :    {{block type="core/template" template="path/to/template.phtml"}}

Comment: I am not good at codes 
please help me what exactly I can use in my case?

Comment: I tried this, but no any success I want to put store switcher in main menu of mobile view{{block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher_top" as="store_switcher_top" template="page/switch/stores-top.phtml"}}